# Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException repository into service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have just set up a new project using Spring Boot V1.3.5 and I keep getting a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to autowire a repository into a service. This is strange because I have other projects set up the same way that work fine.

My Application class.

```
package api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("The API is running.");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

My service.

```
package api.services;

import api.entity.Project;
import api.repository.ProjectRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    /**
     * Saves a project entity into the database.
     *
     * @param project Project
     * @return Project
     */
    public Project save(Project project) {

        return this.projectRepository.save(project);
    }
}
```

My repository.

```
package api.repository;

import api.entity.Project;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {

    Project findByName(String name);
}
```

Now my service gets autowired into my controller but spring doesn't seem to like my repository for some reason.

Can anyone see what is wrong / missing?

Thanks.

The exception message is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private api.repository.ProjectRepository api.services.ProjectService.projectRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [api.repository.ProjectRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Do you have any concrete implementation of your ProjectRepository?  It cannot instantiate just an interface.

Comment: Sure you can't instantiate an interface but I'm not instantiating it, i'm autowiring it. I have the same setup in a different project and that works fine. From the docs "But that’s what makes Spring Data JPA so powerful: You don’t have to write an implementation of the repository interface. Spring Data JPA creates an implementation on the fly when you run the application."

Comment: I tried creating a similar sample project which is available [here](https://github.com/vamsilp/testProjects.git) and it worked for me.Please expose the Project entity class as I am guessing the method signature in the ProjectRepository might incorrect.

Comment: Thats for the resource I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The code has no problem.
Make sure you have correct dependencies.

At one time, I met this same issue, and just found out I was injecting some spring data dependencies but not the **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** which contains a collection of other dependencies, and mine didn't include all the necessary ones.

So put it simple, remove unnecessary dependencies and include the following in your pom.xml (if you're using maven)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

well, check other projects which set up the same way.First, I just notice you have used spring data jpa,so,the annotation @Repository is no need for the interface, because spring boot would scan this automatically.At last, I think you need see this project which has the same configuration with you.
[spring-boot-sample-data-jpa](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa)

Comment: That was the first thing I did. I have also tried without the @Repository annotation and the problem still persists. Thanks I'll take a look.

Comment: Try to add @EnableJpaRepositories("your package for dao") to SpringBootRunner,if your package is not the default scaned package.

Comment: I've tried that already and it didn't work. That shouldn't be necessary anyway as my repository package is part of my api package.

Answer (score -1):

Try @Component instead of @Repository.

Comment: Tried but still the same issue. I thought all stereotypes were picked up by component scan regardless of the type?

Comment: `@Component` is included in the `@Repository` annotation. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html